# R sum in a for loop

Tags: r, loops, sum

I will try to put it in this way:

I'm making a sum :

```
tot <- fac$a[,1]+fac$b[,1]
```

Where a and b are factors and 1 the first column. And until here it's fine.

Now I would like to use  a for loop in order to do the sum for the all columns:

```
tot <- 0 
for (i in 5:13) {
tot[,i] <- fac$a[,i]+fac$b[,i] 
}
```

Which is not working.

Any suggestion?
Thanks.

Comment: @ttmaccer This is very huge. I would like to sum each column line by line and by doing this create a new matrix.

Comment: please make your questions more reproducible in the future. For instance, what is the structure of `fac`? What is the error you got? What were you expecting to get? You'll get infinitely better answers if you put a little thought into your questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I only can guess your problem. (You forgot the error message.)
IMHO it isn't working because `tot` is of class *numeric* and no *matrix* (and has no columns neither any rows which could access by index `i`).

To fix your code: `tot <- matrix(ncol=ncol(fac$a), nrow=nrow(fac$b))`

BTW you should not use a *for loop* for this kind of calculation. Use vectorization instead:

```
a <- matrix(10, ncol=13, nrow=10)
b <- matrix(20, ncol=13, nrow=10)

tot <- a[, 5:13] + b[, 5:13]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, you get exactly what I mean. Thanks for the great advice.